# IIS10 and Visual studio run differently

Tags: asp.net, iis, model-view-controller

I have a dev environment on my laptop running Windows 10. Currently I have an issue of running it on IIS. The project is a system with landing page is a login form to provide access to the admin panel.

- IIS 10 with http://localhost, when click login, the response always return

```
Request URL: http://localhost/
Request Method: POST
Status Code: 302 Found
Remote Address: [::1]:80
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
```

- If I run that project from Visual Studio 2017, the project runs fine, I can login, everything runs as expected.

If I uninstall IIS and install it again. IIS works, but it may comes back to this issue after a few days.

I tried to trace the log from IIS but nothing came up since it's a 302 reponse.

Has anyone encountered this problem?

Comment: You might use FRT to get more info about the 302 responses https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem. The setting of Form Authentication in IIS was somehow disabled. When it disabled, the default response is HTTP 302 Login/Redirect